# How to cleanly do a list with headings and sub-headings?

Tags: php, mysql, database, list, mysqli

I'm trying to make a list with headings by using a database. For example, I want the list to look like this:

```
Programming
- Learn PHP
   - Make a blog using PHP

- Learn Swift
- Learn Ruby
```

As you can see, there's the main header, `Programming` and then the list contents itself. I want to be able to do nested listing as seen below the `Learn PHP` part as well as usual listing. Sorry if this is confusing.

My PHP code here works:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'joshuapriestley');

$data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM goals");

while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["parent_id"] == 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li id=\"list-title\">" . $row["message"] . "</li>";

        $sub = $db->query("SELECT * FROM goals WHERE parent_id = " . $row["id"] . " AND sub_parent_id = 0");
        while($sub_row = $sub->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<li>" . $sub_row["message"];

            $sub2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM goals WHERE sub_parent_id = " . $sub_row["id"]);
            if($sub2->num_rows != 0) {
                echo "<ul>";
                while($sub2_row = $sub2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<li>" . $sub2_row["message"] . "</li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }

            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}               
?>
```

but to me, 3 while loops seem very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? I have a database:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG9vi.png)

The `parent_id` is for the regular items and the `sub_parent_id` is for the sub items.

Here's another image showing the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2aQ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

The while loops aren't the problem per se (performance wise). It's the three queries. But first some notes to begin with:

1. This is a *nested set*. Similar problems: tree storage in database, menu navigation, hierarchical data representation. There are plenty of database layouts and algorithms to query and output them, that are more fitting to provide a single-query solution and work very nicely. I strongly suggest reading up on the nested set model.
2. Your database layout contains a lie: The parent of entry 6 is 5 and not 2. Or your column naming is confusing.

So before you try to reinvent the wheel for the n-th time, use one of the many solutions. Keyword for search engine: nested set (model). There are pros and cons for every solution, there are pages that go into detail if you're interested...

And yes, I've been burned too. The solution that is closest to yours stores the whole path to the node (including the node itself!, which is missing in your solution, the id column is insufficient for that), you can then loop over the list sorted by path and determine opening and closing `<ul/ol>` by looking at the path components (common prefix length = depth). Almost all operations except retrieval are a pain though.